# Laravel | Redirect to verify email if not verified

Tags: php, laravel

Im new to Laravel. Currently, when you visit a page and your account is not verified, nothing happens. I want to make it so if your logged in and your email isnt verified, it will redirect you to the verify email page, but only if your logged in. I tried already but failed.

I made a Middleware with this but it seems not to work.

```
if (Auth::user() && ! Auth::user()->email_verified_at) {
        return redirect('auth/verify');;
}
```

Here is my web.php

```
// Home Page
Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('home');
})->middleware('verifiedEmail');

// Private Page
 Route::get('/private', [HomeController::class, 'private']);


// Home Page
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// Shop Page
Route::get('/shop', 'ShopController@index')->name('shop');

/*
|===========================
| Other Routes
|===========================
*/

// Mailing
Route::get('/email', function() {
  Mail::to($request->user())->send(new MailableClass);
  return new WelcomeMail;
});
Route::get('/sendtestnews', [TestNewsController::class, 
'sendTestNotification']);


// Verification
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Comment: show route for that and also controller method

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed any other files so I only made a middleware

Comment: otherwise we cant assume where the error is

Comment: I added my web.php to the post

Comment: i cant see auth/verify route there.are you using default authentication

Comment: Yeah, Im using the Bulma Auth which is default auth. I added rest of web.php now

Comment: change redirect to   return redirect()->route('verification.notice');;

Comment: Only issue now is im getting "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." when requesting a new email on the page

Comment: verification.notice  route is get method .check my answer

Comment: i have tested it in local .it works fine.also dont specify these routes in web.php

Comment: So what needs changed to allow a new email to be sent? My route list matches yours

Comment: no changes required .check proper mail credentials .if mail username and password contain special character then quote it in env MAIL_PASSWORD=s#D#@$' like this .also specify proper port

Comment: They are correct. They were working when I was manually sending emails. But no matter what I still get the GET method error

Comment: if you have modified verify controller or overriden any think then it works exactly .since i have verified both scenario which you mentioned

Comment: I have not touched the controller

Comment: based on your question code i cant help much.only if you provide some code online testing or git then we can have a look into it.

Comment: Which code would you need?

Comment: as you said you havent default authentication so we might need entire project to test.so better i suggest you to show erorr what you getting in image

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PRYKXpL

Comment: looke like you have defined email/resend manually in your orute

Comment: Using the form you sent gives a 404

Comment: no its just an example .dont use it .it look like this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you  are using wrong url while redirecting it should be

```
 return redirect()->route('verification.notice');
```

To check verify routes.Run following command

```
php artisan route:list
```

this will show all routes defined in `web.php` and `api.php`

```
| POST                                            | email/resend                                       | verification.resend                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@resend                           | web          |
|        |                                        |                                                    |                                               |                                                                                   | auth         |
|        |                                        |                                                    |                                               |                                                                                   | throttle:6,1 |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | email/verify                                       | verification.notice                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@show                             | web          |
|        |                                        |                                                    |                                               |                                                                                   | auth         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | email/verify/{id}/{hash}                           | verification.verify                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@verify                           | web          |
```

**Updated**

```
<form class="d-inline" method="POST" action="email/resend">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="o8OVdlN1Pvu5IrpKvtXybsLiYC0H8czZTW7AIf5Y">                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline">click here to request another</button>.
                    </form>
```

As you can see email/resend form look like above.
`email/resend(route verification.resend )`  is post method